# Div Relative Dentro de tag Center Dentro de Div fixed

Tags: html, css, html5

Quero deixar paginacoes no centro da div e ir crescendo centralmente, mas essa div tem que ser fixa entao pensei em deixar dentro de outra div

relative dentro de outra relative nao se ajusta com o tamanho do conteudo, ao colocar "max-width:100%, width:auto" mesmo havendo pouco conteudo ele ira mostra o valor do max-width.

colocando relative dentro de uma fixed nao centraliza ja perdi muito tempo nisso e estou com um sistema horrivel sem hd

```html
<?php 
 function paginacoes() {
 echo "<center>";
    echo "<div style='background:black; 
          color: white;
          width:auto;
          height: 18px;
          border: 3px solid blak;
          position: relatived; or fixed;
          top: 100px;
          max-width:90%;
         '>";
    $i=1;
    while($i !=26) {
        echo "<div style='background:black; 
              color: white;
              padding-left: 10px;
              padding-right: 10px;
              height: 18px;
              float: left;
              border: 3px solid blak;
              position: relative;
             '>$i</div>";
 $i++;
    }
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</center>";
}
paginacoes();
?>
```

Feliz ano novo!

Answer (score 0):

Consegui! Compartilho ;)

```html
<style>
*{margin:0;padding:0;}

body{height:120%}

#externa {
align-items: center;
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: center;
}
#interna {
top:0px;
position:fixed;
max-width: 200px; /* Valor da Largura do elemento */
background:red;
}
</style>

<div id="externa">
<div id="interna">
asddddddddcc
</div>
</div>
```